# Does PIL resize() hold the GIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, cpython

Example:

```
image = Image.open('foo.png')
# releases the GIL?
resized = image.resize((800, 600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
# reacquires the GIL?
```

Obviously the variable assignment needs to hold the GIL, but it's difficult to break that up into two lines. :)

If there are two threads doing image resizes, can those resizes run on two different cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source of 1.1.7, it doesn't appear to release the GIL for `_resize`.

The functions that release the GIL seem to be:

```
PyImaging_CreateWindowWin32 (createwindow on Win32)
PyImaging_EventLoopWin32 (eventloop on Win32)
pyCMSdoTransform (apply)
_buildTransform (buildTransform)
_buildProofTransform (buildProofTransform)
_encode_to_file (encode_to_file)
```

Comment: The GIL can also be released by the `PyEval_SaveThread()` call, which is called by `ImagingSectionEnter()`, which is called in dozens of places. So the GIL does seem to be released pretty aggressively. (Though apparently not during image load.)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python wiki on the GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock):

> Note that potentially blocking or long-running operations, such as
>   I/O, image processing, and NumPy number crunching, happen outside the
>   GIL. Therefore it is only in multithreaded programs that spend a lot
>   of time inside the GIL, interpreting CPython bytecode, that the GIL
>   becomes a bottleneck.

PIL uses C extensions to do most of its heavy lifting.  So the actual image resizing should take advantage of multi-threads if applicable.

If you are asking about resizing multiple images concurrently, I recommend looking into using Python's native [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library.  This should achieve the desired effect of using multiple cores.

Comment: gevent doesn't let you use multiple cores.

Comment: Just because C extensions are allowed to release the GIL, that doesn't mean that they always do. The extension developer has to explicitly call Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS. http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code